# If two sets $A$ and $C$ do not intersect is the insect A $\cap$ C nothing, or the set of nothing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This is a basic question, but I am unsure of the answer.
If I have sets $A$ and $C$, and the two sets do not intersect, would I notate it as:

$$ A \cap C = \{\emptyset\} $$

or

$$A \cap C = \emptyset$$

I'm leaning towards the first, because $\emptyset$ is an element of all sets right?

Comment: the latter, the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) is not an element of all sets, but it is a subset of every set

Comment: $\varnothing$ is a *subset* of every set.

Comment: The insect is infintetesimal.

Comment: Who else came here for the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means for $A$ and $C$ to be disjoint, or to not intersect, is that they have no elements in common.

Spelling it out, this means that there does not exist $x$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. By definition of intersection, this says exactly that there does not exist $x$ such that $x \in A \cap C$. Thus, $A \cap C$ has no elements.

In summary:
$$A \cap C = \varnothing$$
It is not the case that $\varnothing$ is an element of every set. It is a *subset* of every set, though!